# jQuery Sortable drag over event placeholder disappears after moving out or deleting element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

HTML

```
<div class="mail-area">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="sortable" id="sortable0">
          <li class="ui-state-highlight placeholder">Drop Items here</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Droppable Area ends here -->

<hr>

<div class="snippets">
  <div class="draggable">
    <div>
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#sortable0").sortable({
  revert: true,
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  over: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.parent().find('.placeholder').hide();
  }
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".sortable",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
  stop: function (event,ui) {
            ui.helper.append("<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button>");
            ui.helper.removeAttr("style");
        }
});
$("ul, li").disableSelection();

$(document.body).on("click", ".close", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

jsfiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/89gzq31c/1/

When I move the "Test" Element over the placeholder it disappears as expected. But when I move it out it doesn't reappear. How to achieve this?
In addition after adding an element and deleting it again with the "X" Button the sortable disappears too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

JS

```
$("#sortable0").sortable({
        revert: true,
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find('.placeholder').remove();
        },
    });

$(document.body).on("click", ".close", function () {
    var helpVar = $(this).parent().parent();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if(helpVar.children().length == 0)
    {
        helpVar.append('<li class="ui-state-highlight ui-sortable-handle placeholder">Drop Items here</li>');
    }

});
```